# Calling Directory.CreateDirectory() from within a lock()

Tags: c#

Would it be a bad practice to call Directory.CreateDirectory() from within a lock()? Would it lead to any threading issues?

Answer (score 2):

One does not need a lock as that is additional overhead.  However, appropriate exception handling is needed.

Please refer to this question for further details.

[Is CreateDirectory() in C# thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572736/is-createdirectory-in-c-sharp-thread-safe)